# Shannon Entropy: one variable is function of the other, bijective vs injective case

Tags: function, code-injection, entropy, information-theory

We have 2 random variables `X` and `Y` and `Y` is a function of `X`, `f(X)`.

It seems obvious that `H(X|Y) = 0 = H(Y|X)` if `f(X)` is a *bijective* function, as there is an unambiguous mapping between domain and codomain.

What I find confusing is the case when `f(X)` is an *injective* function.
I think that this case should be equivalent to the bijective case, and that's why:
`H(X|Y)` shoud be `0`, because if I have the value of `f(X)`, I can only have one value for `X`.
`H(Y|X)` should be `0` because every `X` maps to exactly one value in the codomain.

Is my way of hinking correct? It just seems a ittle bit weird to me that there is no difference between a bijective and an injective function in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct! And it should not be that strange in the end. I think it is best to come back to the definition of entropy. Here, I would in particular try to understand what `H(f(X))` is.

In general, you have that `H(X) = - sum_x p(x)*log(p(x))`, so the question to ask is when computing the entropy of `f(X)`, what do these probabilities `p(x)`'s become? 
As you correctly pointed out, when the function is bijective, the probability of an element `y=f(x)` is simply `p(y)=p(x)` since an elment `x` maps to a unique `y`, and so that is why in this case you have `H(X)=H(f(X))`. In fact, the same holds for injective functions since an element `x` is also uniquely mapped to a `y`, so the probabilities do not change once again. It becomes different when your function is surjective, in which case multiple `x`'s may map to the same `y`. In this case, you would get `p(y) = sum_x' p(x')`, where `x'` are the elements mapping to `y`. So because the distributions do not always match, you can see that when computing the entropy of `f(X)`, it will not necessarily be the same as the entropy of `X`.

Now going back to your question about the conditional entropy, using the chain rule you get that `H(X|f(X))=H(X, f(X))-H(f(X)) = H(X)-H(f(X)) =H(X)-H(X) = 0` when `f` is bijective or injective by the argument above.

In the same way, you get `H(f(X)|X)=H(X, f(X))-H(X)) = H(X)-H(X) = 0`, and this is valid for any deterministic function `f` (no need for injectivity or anything).

Hope it helps!